# How to make cake like almond squares into fudgy like Squares?

Tags: baking

I made Almond Paste Squares that turned out delicious, but too cake like for what I wanted.  The recipe had these ingredients: 1 C butter, softened; 1 C flour; 2/3 C sugar; 1 tsp baking powder; 3 eggs. Then this 1 C almond paste; 2/3 C granulated sugar; 2 eggs; 1 tsp almond flavoring; Sliced almonds, Opt.  The two batters then mixed together.

What can I do to make these more fudgy like brownies?

Answer (score 2):

A hint is that a lot of brownie recipes don't include any leavening agent at all, so I recommend you reduce the baking powder amount, to about 1/2 tsp.

Also, it may help to replace part of the whole eggs with egg-yolks, as the richness in the yolks make for a fudgier treat.

Comment: A good point as well.

Answer (score 1):

### Cook for less time.

The exact same brownie recipe can be delectably fudgy or horribly cake-like from a difference of 5 minutes in the cooking time.